# strange WebKit Error in UIWebView - can this be catched?

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, webkit, crash

I'm loading some HTML / JS from a subdirectory of my documents directory on iPad into a UIWebView. Everything works fine so far. For debugging the JS - Part i've put some `alert(..);` statements in the JS-File. Most of the time there is no problem with this alerts, but now and then there raises an error in console and the App crashes:

`WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:initiatedByFrame: delegate: <(null)> A route has already been registered for class 'Publication' and HTTP method 'ANY'`

Question 1: What could be the problem? I mean ... it is a simple alert(); what seems to cause this error in console.

Question 2: can i catch this errors in my app? This way the app wouldn't crash because of a simple JS alert();

Thanks

Comment: is there no way to catch WebKit Errors and handle them? I couldn't find information about the errorDomain or Codes.

Comment: I'm looking for a way too :( You should vote the question up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a JavaScriptAlert category to your UIWebView class. JavaScriptAlert+UIWebView.h

Override the method:

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)sender runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(id)frame;
```

This should handle the alerts from JavaScript.

Then on the javascript side of things, if you are not running in debug mode, you can set the alert or console log to a no-op function. Something like

```
var noop = function () {};
console.log = noop;
window.alert = noop;
```